# React using defaultProptypes and propTypes check, with undefined prop

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

Without special invitation I was on React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) aiming to play with the idea of defaultProps. I got TypeError that I can not understand!

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.defaultProps = {
  name: 'Stranger'
};

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
};

ReactDOM.render(<Greeting/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Result:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
```

Pointing to (in Sources):

```
name: _react.PropTypes.string
```

As you read in documentation: 
The propTypes typechecking happens after defaultProps are resolved, so typechecking will also apply to the defaultProps.

If I remove:

```
Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string, //.isRequired
};
```

There will be no TypeError! 

Please, how I could understand this and have both propTypes and defaultProps without getting TypeError if I didn't explicitly provide a prop that has a default value assigned (which is why default value exists)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that `PropTypes` is undefined, meaning there is an issue with what you're importing. You should import `PropTypes` from `prop-types`:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Thanks. I imported it, but as "import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';"

Comment: and the funny is that I was practicing by a video tutorial that was not updated, only your answer recalled me that it's updated and no more where I imported from!